# C# - Google Drive API not redirecting

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have chosen Installed Application as project in Google Console. After making Windows Form project, i am trying to authenticate user which i successfully did it but only for once. It did not redirected me to Google authentication site for the second time. 
[image]

Please help me. Am i making any mistake in code?

Comment: you should copy your code into the question not a screen shot we cant test that.

Answer (score 0):

The Google .net client library uses fileDatastore to store your credentials for "user"  you are sending Enviorment.Username.  So it knows its the same user and will not request your authentication again.   Your code is working correctly.

Credentials are being stored in your %appData% directory

I have a full article on how filedatastore works here if you are interested in learning more about it [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i have read the article but i am still unable to figure out what should i do to bring the authorization screen every time user access the API using Client ID and Client Secret. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you do not want your application to cache/remember the previous login. Not sure why you want to do that, but if that is really what you want, I guess you can just delete the file your %appData% directory if it exist.

Comment: instead of sending Enviorment.Username send a random number.   However this is kind of defeating the point of Oauth2.   Or you can revoke it everytime your application closes.

Comment: Also some related information at https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/463